# OCaml function parameter pattern matching for strings

Tags: ocaml

I tried to pass a string in to get a reversed string. Why can't I do this:

```
let rec reverse x = 
  match x with
  | "" -> ""
  | e ^ s -> (reverse s) ^ e;;
```

The compiler says it's a syntax error. Can't I use `^` to destructure parameters?

Comment: Additionally for the explanation below: Where in the string should the compiler even split the string? "abc" to "a" "bc" or "ab" "c"

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The reason for this is that strings are not represented as a datatype in the same way as lists are.  Therefore, while cons `(::)` is a constructor, `^` is *not*.  Instead, strings are represented as a lower level type without a recursive definition (as lists are).  There is a way to match strings as a list of characters, using a function from SML (which you can write in OCaml) called `explode` and `implode` which -- respectively -- take a string to a char list and vice versa.  [Here's an example implementation of them.](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/old_caml_site/Examples/oc/basics/explode.ml)

Comment: Thanks. But is anyway to 'overload' the operand like C++ do? That will definitely better the abstraction.

Comment: No.  There's no way to overload the operator.  Strings are defined as a lower level type, and you can't artificially impose them into a datatype when they're fundamentally _not_ an inductively defined type.

Answer (score 5):

As [Kristopher Micinski explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9863036/ocaml-function-parameter-pattern-matching-for-strings#9863069), you can't decompose strings using pattern matching as you do with lists.

But you can convert them to lists, using `explode`. Here's your `reverse` function with pattern matching using `explode` and its counterpart `implode`:

```
let rec reverse str =
  match explode str with
    [] -> ""
    | h::t -> reverse (implode t) ^ string_of_char h
```

Use it like this:

```
let () =
  let text = "Stack Overflow ♥ OCaml" in
  Printf.printf "Regular: %s\n" text;
  Printf.printf "Reversed: %s\n" (reverse text)
```

Which shows that it works for single-byte characters but not for multi-byte ones.

And here are `explode` and `implode` along with a helper method:

```
let string_of_char c = String.make 1 c

(* Converts a string to a list of chars *)
let explode str =
  let rec explode_inner cur_index chars = 
    if cur_index < String.length str then
      let new_char = str.[cur_index] in
      explode_inner (cur_index + 1) (chars @ [new_char])
    else chars in
  explode_inner 0 []

(* Converts a list of chars to a string *)
let rec implode chars =
  match chars with
    [] -> ""
    | h::t ->  string_of_char h ^ (implode t)
```

Answer (score 3):

When you write a pattern matching expression, you cannot use arbitrary functions in your patterns. You can only use *constructors*, which look like *unevaluated* functions. For example, the function "+" is defined on integers. So the expression `1+2` is evaluated and gives 3; the function "+" is evaluated, so you cannot match on `x+y`. Here is an attempt to define a function on natural numbers that checks whether the number is zero:

```
 let f x =  match x with
  | 0 -> false
  | a+1 -> true
 ;;
```

This cannot work! For the same reason, your example with strings cannot work. The function "^" is evaluated on strings, it is not a constructor.

The matching on `x+1` would work only if numbers were  unevaluated symbolic expressions made out of the unevaluated operator `+` and a symbolic constant `1`. This is not the case in OCAML. Integers are implemented directly through machine numbers.

When you match a variant type, you match on constructors, which are unevaluated expressions. For example:

```
 # let f x = match x with
    | Some x -> x+1
    | None -> 0
 ;;
 val f : int option -> int = <fun>
```

This works because the `'a option` type is made out of a symbolic expression, such as `Some x`. Here, `Some` is not a function that is evaluated and gives some other value, but rather a "constructor", which you can think of as a function that is never evaluated. The expression `Some 3` is not evaluated any further; it remains as it is. It is only on such functions that you can pattern-match.

Lists are also symbolic, unevaluated expressions built out of constructors; the constructor is `::`. The result of `x :: y :: []` is an unevaluated expression, which is represented by the list `[x;y]` only for cosmetic convenience. For this reason, you can pattern-match on lists.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It would be great if you could mention if and how pattern matching on strings is possible in OCaml.