# Is there a way to `match` on a string that starts with some value?

Tags: ocaml

For example, consider the following expression:

```
match string with
| "Foo " ^ rest -> rest
| "Bar " ^ rest -> rest
| _ -> "unmatched"
```

Unfortunately, this is a [syntax error](https://reasonml.github.io/en/try?rrjsx=true&ocaml=LYQwLgxgFgBAzmATgSwHYHMYHdligKAB8YAiAMQHsLSYA9GRAUwRgFoA%20B5sI0gIRCIa9Jiw5cEvAPptOJAK6pQkKIwAmJIA). Is there some way to achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some explanations in [OCaml function parameter pattern matching for strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9863036/ocaml-function-parameter-pattern-matching-for-strings) on why it's not possible to deconstruct strings in pattern-matching. You can only match on plain strings.

Instead, you could use the new [`String.starts_with`](https://ocaml.org/api/String.html#VALstarts_with) (OCaml 4.13) to compare the string with a fixed prefix, or use the [`Str`](https://ocaml.org/api/Str.html) module that provides regular expressions, or convert the string to a list and match on that list.

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility is to split the string going into your match, so that you can match based on a tuple of plain old strings.

```
String.(
  match sub s 0 4, sub s 4 (length s - 4) with 
  | "foo ", rest -> ...
  | "bar ", rest -> ...
  | _ -> ...
)
```

If you create a function to partition a string on a certain number of characters, this becomes nicer to look at.

```
let part s n =
  String.(sub s 0 n, sub s n (length s - n))
```

Now:

```
match part s 4 with 
| "foo ", rest -> ...
| "bar ", rest -> ...
| _ -> ...
```

If we were to not use pattern-matching, this might look like:

```
let (first, rest) = part s 4 in
if first = "foo " then ...
else if first = "bar " then ...
else ...
```